# Написал небольшую программу для нахождения корня и засунул в customtkinter, но когда я поставил тему, тема осталась такой-же. Что делать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

Написал небольшую программу для нахождения корня, попросил нейронку эту прогу засунуть в *customtkinter*. Я сразу прописал`customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")`.  Код работает, но тема все так же дефолтная. Вот код:

```
def calculate():
    try:
        h = int(entry_h.get())
        g = var_g.get()
        if h <= 0:
            label_result.configure(text='Пожалуйста, введите корректное число')
        else:
            if g == 2:
                s = sqrt(h)
                label_result.configure(text=f'квадратный корень из {h} = {s}')
            elif g == 3:
                s = h ** (1/3)
                label_result.configure(text=f'Кубический корень из {h} = {s}')
            elif g == 1:
                n = int(entry_n.get())
                if n <= 0:
                    label_result.configure(text='Пожалуйста, введите корректное значение n')
                else:
                    s = h ** (1./n)
                    label_result.configure(text=f'N корень из {h} = {s}')
            else:
                label_result.configure(text='Произошла ошибка')
    except ValueError:
        label_result.configure(text='Пожалуйста, введите корректное число')

window = ctk.CTk()
window.title('Калькулятор корней')
window.geometry('600x200')  # задаем размер окна
ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

frame = ctk.CTkFrame(window)
frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

label_h = ctk.CTkLabel(frame, text='Ваше число для поиска корня:', width=120)
label_h.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
entry_h = ctk.CTkEntry(frame, width=120)
entry_h.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

var_g = ctk.IntVar()
radio_2 = ctk.CTkRadioButton(frame, text='квадратный корень', variable=var_g, value=2, width=120)
radio_2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
radio_3 = ctk.CTkRadioButton(frame, text='кубический корень', variable=var_g, value=3, width=120)
radio_3.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
radio_1 = ctk.CTkRadioButton(frame, text='N корень', variable=var_g, value=1, width=120)
radio_1.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

label_n = ctk.CTkLabel(frame, text='введите N степень для нахождения корня:', width=120)
label_n.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
entry_n = ctk.CTkEntry(frame, width=120)
entry_n.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

button_calculate = ctk.CTkButton(frame, text='Рассчитать', command=calculate, width=20)
button_calculate.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
label_result = ctk.CTkLabel(frame, text='', width=20)
label_result.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3)

window.mainloop()
```

Так же буду рад, если подскажите как сделать качество тулбоксов , кнопок и всего текста в целом лучше, т.к. при исполнении кода все выглядит очень пиксельно. Заранее спасибо

P.s :
Ребят, не судите мой вопрос строго, я только недавно начал изучать Python.Понимающих благодарю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для тёмной темы Вы должны добавить в свой код строчку `ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")` перед `ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")`
Насчёт пикселей не совсем понял, всё выглядит вполне хорошо:
[image: Приложение]